# Android Studio - Unit Tests Simulate App Restart

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, android-studio, restart

Hello I would like to use Unit Tests to see if my Data Save Structe is working the problem is, that I have no Idea how to Simulate a Restart programmatically.

Here is a Example Unit Test.

(AppData is just a Class to save various Things like a Shopping List with multiple Entries.)

```
@Test
    public void getDataAfterRestart(){
        //Save a Entry
        AppData appData = new AppData();
        appData.addShoppingEntry(new ShoppingEntry("Bread"));
        appData.save();


        //************************
        //Restart the Application*
        //************************


        //After the App reopend it self check if the Entry is still here
        int entries = appData.getShoppingEntries().size();

        assertEquals(1,entries);
}
```

What are some good practices, to deal with problems like this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Restarting your app implies that you need to interact with the underlying Android operating system in order to test the correct behavior. This means you need to write an Instrumented Test rather than a Unit Test. In Android, we write Instrumented tests using the tools provided in the [Testing Library in AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/set-up-project). In this case, you probably need to use [UI Automator](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-automator) in order to interact with the device directly to stop your app and then restart it.

Comment: Most of us know that, but the quastion is also how to do it as this is not easy at all or documented or anything, I am actually struggling to find a way how to correctly terminate and start app again using uiautomator.

Comment: @Renetik If you have a separate question, you should click the "Ask a Question" button and fill out the form. This area is for comments, including clarification of the answer.